# Generate a list from another function which returns a Bool in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

i'm currently working on lists of lists (which we use to represent a grid).
I have one function which receive 2 arguments (my grid and a tuple of 4 Integers) and it returns a Boolean.

Now with a new function, I need to generate a list of every tuples which returns True for a certain grid. For exemple, `function1 (1,3,2,2) grid1` will return `True` so I need to get `(1,3,2,2)` in my list.

The other problem is that I have multiple conditions to respect for my tuple `(a,b,c,d)` of 4 Integers such as : `1 <= a < a+c <= n and 1 <= b < b+d <= m` where `n` is the number of lines (so length grid) and `m` is the number of columns (so length (head grid)).

I had the idea to use map but so far I never used it in such a situation and everything I tried failed.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a job for list comprehensions. Have you learned about them yet?

Comment: I have indeed, but I only used them in simple situations where only 1 variable is iterating. How could I do this with 4 different variables, also keeping in mind that I need to test every possibility (so, not only (1,1,1,1), (2,2,2,2), but (3,4,1,2) aswell as (4,3,1,2) for exemple) and I also need to specify somewhere the conditions I stated in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic approaches for doing this in Haskell.

1. Generate a stream of tuples that satisfy the constaints you listed but don't necessarily return true according to the function
2. Use `filter` to par down the list

Or we can try to avoid generating all that redundant data and just have something like

1. Use our knowledge of the predicate to only generate a stream of valid tuples in the first place

Since we're working with an arbitrary function, we can't really do the second so we'll opt for the former. Thus we start by generating all of the tuples satisfying the constaints `1 <= a < a + c <= n` and `1 <= b < b + d <= m`.

Now it's clear that `a` is in the range `[1 .. n]` and `b` is in `[1 .. m]`. Furthermore, for each `a` we can have `c` in `[a + 1 .. n - a]` and for each `b` we can have `[b + 1 .. m - b]`. We'll use [Haskell's list comprehensions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension) to encode this is a very snazzy way

```
allTuples :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int, Int)]
allTuples n m = -- First we take in n, m
  [(a, b, c, d) |
    a <- [1 .. n],
    b <- [1 .. m],
    c <- [a + 1 .. n - a],
    d <- [b + 1 .. m - b]]
```

Here these `<-` will do the right thing and take all possible combinations. Next all we need do is use [`filter`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#maps-and-filters) to remove elements.

```
 prune :: Grid -> [(Int, Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int, Int)]
 prune grid tuples = filter (\t -> f grid t) tuples
 -- could have written:
 -- prune grid = filter (f grid)
 -- prune = filter . f
```

Then we can glue them together, but I'll leave this final step to you because I'm not sure how you'll use it in your application. You can also merge these steps into a single list comprehension:

```
allTuples :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int, Int)]
allTuples n m = -- First we take in n, m
  [(a, b, c, d) |
    a <- [1 .. n],
    b <- [1 .. m],
    c <- [a + 1 .. n - a],
    d <- [b + 1 .. m - b],
    f grid (a, b, c, d)]
```

Comment: You can just as easily integrate the filtering into the comprehension. Depending on the filter(s), that could even be much more efficient.

Comment: @dfeuer Absolutely, I think it's conceptually clearer to separate the two though and it should perform identically in this usage because the results will stream nicely. I've updated with a note though

Comment: My point about efficiency is that sticking conditions *between* enumerations can avoid a lot of wasted work.

Comment: Oh that's fair, is that relevant here though? @dfeuer

Comment: No way to know, under the circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Didn't know you could write comprehensions lists like that. My problem is solved.